# Why doesn't Batman kill?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight

Why does Batman not kill?

He could have at least killed the Joker in *The Dark Knight* when he had the chance instead of handing him to the law. He would've done the world a great favour.

Comment: Batman kills people all the time. Mainly it's tossing henchmen over buildings. All off screen.

Comment: People if you don't have serious  answer dont bother commenting. This question already got an answer.  And this is not facebook comment page. Everything is taken seriously in here.

Comment: Seriously, Batman has killed many people https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3wM7_Bch1Y

Comment: The best way to get an answer to this question is to watch/read more and more Batman stories. It comes up a lot

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Bruce Wayne knows that he's a disturbed individual with violent tendencies and unresolved issues, and could easily slide towards evil. To stop that from happening he created a set of ground rules for himself, a code of ethics. No killing, and no guns.

Interestingly enough, this wasn't always the case. The very early Batman stories in the 1940's he was shown using guns and killing criminals. This didn't last long and the now familiar rules were now put in place.

These rules have created some very interesting stories. The Joker in particular, and Batman's unwillingness to kill him is a constant dilemma for the caped crusader. Watch *Batman: Under the Red Hood* for a very interesting story about that very same dilemma.

Comment: The fact that his parents were **killed** with a **gun** might also have some influence on his code of ethics. This was nicely portrayed in "Batman Begins", in the harbour scene, when he looks at the gun, gets flashes of the murder, and then - disgusted by the gun - tosses it into the water.

Comment: @VedranŠego: Can't upvote ur comment enough!

Comment: Interestingly, he had a chance to kill his parents' murderer (Joe Chill or what was his name) in one comic episode, and he was willing to use gun in that episode. I don't want to spoil so I'll stop here.